# Unable to access struts2 application

Tags: struts2, glassfish-3

In my project we were using glassfish2.x now we are planning to upgrade to glassfish3.x. When deploying a WAR file in gf2 is working but same WAR file in gf3.x giving below error while accessing :
"The Struts dispatcher cannot be found. This is usually caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]" 
However,  application is deploying properly in gf3.x. 
**Error is showing line number of one jsp file where I have used struts tag

I am using struts2-core-2.1.5.jar and
Glassfish 3.1.2.  I tried all ways like requesting URL with .action or if struts2 jar is corrupted,etc
But still facing issue.
Please suggest.

Comment: If you're accessing a JSP page directly, and it contains an S2 tag, this is a reasonable error to get. In fact I'm more concerned that you *weren't* getting the error before. Without any actual information beyond the containers it's impossible to help.

Comment: Is there any way to configure S2 tag in application or it would take once we deploy struts application.We give tag-uri as /struts-tags(<%@taglib  prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>), how this S2(/struts-tags) is been provided to JSP, usually we wont specify this.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: To use struts tags we specify <%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %> tag. In this we are just stating /struts-tags however we are not keeping any tld file so from where JSP picks tag library for struts2? And how glassfish2 is able to find classpath but not glassfish3.

Comment: ... The issue isn't the tags, it's how you're accessing the JSP. You're not really providing anything anyone can use to diagnose.

Comment: On my development system I attached Glassfish 3 prelude in Netbeans and took build for my project, deployed it in gf3 prelude server, It worked, but same WAR I tried to deploy In gf3.1.2 which is installed in new different linux system, it deployed with no error but giving same exception on accessing URL.
What could be the issue..?What mistake I am making?
I am using struts2-core-2.3.20.jar this time.

Comment: Whenever I am removing <auth-constraint> of <security-constraint> from web.xml it is not giving struts exception
instead it toggling between login page and index page.
What could be the issue? Please help out...

Comment: HOW ARE YOU ACCESSING THE JSP PAGE

Comment: Making action entry and calling action...Ex : <action name="toindex">
<result type="redirect">index.jsp</result>
</action>...

What is relation of that security constraint and struts?? Even I debug and tried whenever any exception is coming it is giving "struts dispatcher not found exception" however it has already gone through few actions...

Comment: If you redirect to jsp you're not going through an action.

Comment: What you suggest Dave??
I used dispatcher in place of redirect of result and even without specifying any type...It gave me same result...It is going through interceptor... I am removing <auth-constraint> part in web.xml and able to see login page but it is toggling with index page..